# Start page background on bottom from both sides - CSS

Tags: css, background-image

I have a page having a background image for `<body>`. The image may only stay bottom of the page and visible across x and I don't want it repeat whole body across x and y.

The image looks something like below;

[image: Tile]

I want this image to tile over x, but want to repeat from both sides left and right. The image may start from both left and right sides;

[image: Structure]

In between them is the content `<div>` By doing this, the image may be look as if it has width of whole page. I can simply do this using `repeat-x`, but it will create some incomplete tile portion at the end portion.

The completed page may look something like image below;

[image]

Is this possible with CSS? I think you get what I am talking about. If you want extra information, just comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write  like this:

```
div{
 background:url(image1.jpg) repeat-x bottom left,url(image1.jpg) repeat-x bottom right;
}
```

Comment: write like this background-color:red;

Comment: it is not working along with the above code. did u test the full code?